# How to get the correct size browser viewport?

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

I just started learning web front end and I have a question - is there any difference between resizing the viewport after using developer mode (F12) and resizing the viewport after clicking on responsive design?

I have the code below.

```
body {
  background-color: pink;
}

@media (min-width: 30em) {
  body {
    background-color: blue
  }
}
```

So based on the code above, the color of the background should be blue if the browser viewport is wider than 30em.

After opening the developer mode, I clicked the responsive design button and resized the viewport, but found that no matter how I resized it, the background color was still blue.

Please see the gif picture:
[No matter what sizes of the viewport I resized, the color is still blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Q4z.gif)

But when I dragged and resized the window of the developer tool, I noticed the background color turned pink!

Gif Picture:
[Background color turned pink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ3D1.gif)

I'm confused and hope someone can help me out.

Thank you in advance!

When I was learning responsive design by using HTML tags, like using  element, I clicked on the Responsive Design Mode button and then resized the viewport, and it worked! But now it's failing...

Comment: I am not seeing the problem as you describe it using the code you have given so far. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is working just fine. and there should not be much difference. Basically there is a responsive design section which allows it to see in different viewport sizes, aspect ratio , etc

Comment: Hi @innocent I just re-edited my question and I added 2 gifs, hopefully this will make my question description clearer. Could you please re-read my question? Thanks for your time!

Comment: i believe your browser is tripping. I am still not able to reproduce it. did you try it in other browsers

Comment: @innocent Yes, my Chrome browser may have tripped, I just downloaded Firefox, opened that HTML document, tried again, and it worked! Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @innocent's suggestion, I tried using Firefox to open my HTML document and found that it worked - the background color changed to pink when the viewport size was less than 30em.